# Why it's not input 3 times

Tags: c

When I use `%s` in `scanf` function then it gets 3 times input but when I use new line until we get new line it will take 3 times input. But it's not working. Where is my problem?

```
int main()
{
    char str[100][100];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        scanf("%[^\n]",str[i]);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s",str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. Show your input and what you actually get. From the question it’s a bit unclear what is “gets 3 times input” or “take 3 times input”

Answer (score 0):

*Question is bit unclear* but small suggestion that Better use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` if you want to scan char array with white spaces(that might be your intention)

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    fgets(str[i],sizeof(str[i],stdin));
```

Comment: Sure you can use scanf() but fgets() is preferred and advisable

Comment: While using scanf() buffer may not clear everytime so may need to clear stdin buffer using getchar() or some other stuff.